# Bread bowls verus loaf of bread

Tags: bread

I am making bread bowls for soup.  I made extra dough for a loaf, do you think there is a difference making a loaf from a bread bowl recipe?  The Bread Bowl recipe seems like a pretty standard bread recipe.

Answer (score 1):

It will make a wonderful bread with lots of holes and a tough crust. Whether that's good for you or not is really whatever you like or not.

It bake the bread bagette style or free bread style right on the stone instead of using a loaf pan, but that's just me.